# Need to use getopts with one argument OR another

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, getopts

```
while getopts gpr: | gpd: name
do
   case $name in
      g) echo " -g";;
      p) echo " -p";;
      r) echo " -r with '$OPTARG'";;
      d) echo " -d with '$OPTARG'";;
   esac
done
```

I know this is wrongly written. I wanted to write it that way so it would show what I need it to do.

Script with g, p, d OR r options. The key thing is that OR.

I have tried to google it, read manuals, found many easy examples.
Question is if there is a way to do this or getopts doesnt support this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
have_r=false
have_d=false

while getopts gpr:d: name; do
   case $name in
      g) echo " -g";;
      p) echo " -p";;
      r) echo " -r with '$OPTARG'"; have_r=true;;
      d) echo " -d with '$OPTARG'"; have_d=true;;
   esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

if $have_r && $have_d; then
   echo "error, cannot use both -r and -d" >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will stop processing options after the first one of `-g`, `-p`, `-r`, or `-d` is parsed. You can take stronger action if desired inside the `if` statement (issue a warning, exit the script, etc).

```
while getopts gpr:d: name
do
   if (( option_found == 1 )); then
       break
   fi
   case $name in
      g) echo " -g"; option_found=1;;
      p) echo " -p"; option_found=1;;
      r) echo " -r with '$OPTARG'"; option_found=1;;
      d) echo " -d with '$OPTARG'"; option_found=1;;
   esac
done
```

By itself, `getopts` does not enforce any kind of mutual exclusivity on the options used.